# How to automatically create all child objects of a parent class in python?

Tags: python, list, oop

I want to automate the creation of objects for all child classes of a parent class.For example:
This is the parent class

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod
class Parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def fetch(self):
        # some code here
```

Now I create child classes for this parent class

```
#child classes
class obj1(Parent):
    def fetch(self):
       # some code

class obj2(Parent):
    def fetch(self):
       # some code

class obj3(Parent):
    def fetch(self):
       # some code
```

Now my problem is I want to create one object for all these children classed here automatically and save them in an objectList.So that **even if someone creates a new child class later, the code will automatically create an object for that new child class and append it in the objectList.**

I can do this manually by:

```
objectList = []
objectList.append(obj1())
objectList.append(obj2())
objectList.append(obj3())
```

But if someone creates a new child for example obj4() I have to manually append obj4.
How to create an object of all child classes automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python3, subclasses are registered automatically, and made available via the `__subclasses__` method:

```
objectList = [cls() for cls in Parent.__subclasses__()]
```

Could also use a Metaclass, although then you end up with all the classes in your list, including Parent:

```
class MetaParent(type):
  subclasses = []
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, kwargs):
    kls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, kwargs)
    cls.subclasses.append(kls())
    return kls

class Parent(metaclass=MetaParent):
  pass

class ChildA(Parent):
  pass

class ChildB(Parent):
  pass
```

Now MetaParent.subclasses will have all your instances. Filter out instances of Parent if you want: `[cls for cls in MetaParent.subclasses if not type(Parent) == cls]`

Comment: upvoted, but I guess op wants this to automatically happen every time a new subclass is created

Comment: Yeah, the problem with my solution is you must do this after all the subclasses have been defined. Conceivably you could get fancier by using a metaclass to do this.

Comment: I was thinking something like `__new__` doing something but yeah metaclass would also work

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to metaclasses, you could use [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__), which gets called whenever a class is subclassed.

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod

object_list = []
class Parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def fetch(self):
        # some code here
        pass
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        object_list.append(cls())
```

Note, it is a special-case class method, i.e., it gets the *class* as the first argument.

Of course, this depends on you knowing how these classes are meant to be instantiated (here with no arguments).

In the repl:

```
In [3]: #child classes
   ...: class obj1(Parent):
   ...:     def fetch(self):
   ...:        # some code
   ...:        pass
   ...:
   ...: class obj2(Parent):
   ...:     def fetch(self):
   ...:        # some code
   ...:        pass
   ...:
   ...: class obj3(Parent):
   ...:     def fetch(self):
   ...:        # some code
   ...:        pass
   ...:

In [4]: object_list
Out[4]:
[<__main__.obj1 at 0x7fd233c23990>,
 <__main__.obj2 at 0x7fd233c23050>,
 <__main__.obj3 at 0x7fd233c23650>]
```